# Groupby to count the number of calls on different days by id

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe like the one below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2013-04-19', '2013-04-19', '2013-04-20', '2013-04-20', '2013-04-19'],
              'id': [1,2,2,3,1]})
```

I need to create another dataframe containing only the id and the number of calls made on different days. An example of output is as follows:

```
Id  |  Count
1   |  1
2   |  2
3   |  1
```

What I'm trying so far:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['id','date']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'COUNT'})
df2
```

However, the way out is far from desired. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you share the current output and expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow *"the number of calls made on different days"*.  Do you want to count days? calls? unique days that calls were made?

Comment: a bit strange, I'd say your code does exactly as you've stated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [**`.nunique()`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) to count the *unique* days per id:

```
table.groupby('id').date.nunique()
```

This gives us a series:

```
>>> df.groupby('id').date.nunique()
id
1    1
2    2
3    1
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

You can make use of [**`.to_frame()`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) to convert it to a dataframe:

```
>>> df.groupby('id').date.nunique().to_frame('count')
    count
id       
1       1
2       2
3       1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pd.Dataframe function to convert the result into a dataframe and further rename the columns as per you like.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2013-04-19', '2013-04-19', '2013-04-20', '2013-04-20', '2013-04-19'],
              'id': [1,2,2,3,1]})

x = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('id').date.nunique().reset_index())
x.columns = ['Id', 'Count']
print(x)
```

Comment: `reset_index(name='Count')` saves you the renaming.

Comment: thanks @Quang. The reason I did like that cuz the i in "Id" was Capital.